# Rollup says "[name] is not exported by [file]" while it clearly is

Tags: typescript, svelte, rollupjs

I am building a Svelte/TypeScript application and all of a sudden it won't compile anymore, with the following error:

```
[!] Error: 'VoidPromiseCallback' is not exported by src/types.ts, imported by src/TopicEditionFormStack/TopicEditionFormStack.svelte
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
src/TopicEditionFormStack/TopicEditionFormStack.svelte (2:18)
1: <script lang="ts">
2:   import { Topic, VoidPromiseCallback } from '../types.js';
                     ^
```

However if you look at file `src/types.ts` you see at the end:

```js
export type VoidPromiseCallback = {
  resolve: () => void,
  reject: (reason?: any) => void,
}
```

VS Code agrees that `types.ts` does export the name, since if I do *“go to definition”* on the occurrence of `VoidPromiseCallback` Rollup complains about, it navigates to the export quoted above.

Any idea what could cause this? I was thinking maybe Rollup did not invalidate a cache regarding the exports of `types.ts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a svelte component you will need to import your types by specifying that what you import is a type:

```
import { Topic } from '../types.js';
import type { VoidPromiseCallback } from '../types.js';
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! I didn't think about that because the other “types” I was importing were actually classes, and the rule seems to be a bit different with classes, you only need `import type` if all the classes are only used as types. Not sure how long I would have spent debugging without your answer!